# How to define the user as a stale user in azure active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In on premises active directory, how a stale user is defined depends on last logon and last password reset activity. I want to know how to define a user as a stale user after some period of time in azure active directory.

Answer (score -1):

Azure AD does not provide direct feature for identifying stale user.

Below article can help

https://www.undocumented-features.com/2018/06/22/how-to-find-staleish-azure-b2b-guest-accounts/

Below text borrowed from the above blog:

This script uses the RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime property from the user in conjunction with one of the following:

- default token refresh lifetime in Azure AD (90 days)
- the actual token refresh lifetime if a policy has been configured and is able to be read
- a user-specified value

This will help you identify when users last logged on (using the RefreshTokensValidFromDateTimeProperty), and then, based on the tenant’s refresh token setting and a “stale” value (how long you want to specify without a refresh token being updated), lets you calculate a stale user.

Script available at

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Report-on-Azure-AD-Stale-8e64c1c5

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but  this is not right way to define as stale. because refreshTokensValidFromDateTime is not refreshing during user logged in, so we can't check when the user is logged in.